# Why httpResponse()->redirect() doesnt work if running from Visual Studio

Tags: php, visual-studio

I have a php website running fine.

I used notepad++ to edit it, but i installed Visual Studio 2019 and PHP Tools to be able to work faster and doing php debug.

If i run the website from Visual Studio, the first page is OK, but when i go on the :

```
 $this->app->httpResponse()->redirect('/saisie_temps.html');
```

My browser doesn't find the html page :

[image]

-> Whereas all is runing fine is i launch the website outside of Visual Studio.
Any ideas why ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: code editors does not effect the page it slef you have other problem which is make sure that you file path are in the right place

Comment: is it in the same directory as index.html?

Comment: My website is loaded by a bootstrap.php file in the root folder. I have a route.xml file with : "   <route url="/saisie_temps.html" module="Saisie" action="saisie" security="1"></route>". I don't understand why it's ok outside of VS and not if running with it.

Comment: Some news...i run bootstrap.php in debug and my variable : __DIR__ is containing : xdebug: , or, it may contain my root folder isn't it ?

Comment: I corrected my DIR variable...but still the same issue :(

Comment: Some news...if i go deep in debug, there is :     header('Location: '.$location); where $location is "./saisie_temps.php". But i still don't know why it's ok outside of VS Studio and OK in VS STudio